# Filter dictionary based on value in list of nested dictionary

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have the following dictionary that contains a list, in which the individual elements are nested dictionaries.

```
id_config = {
  'expectations' : [
    {
      "kwargs": {
        "column": "id",
        "value": 14
      },
      "expectation_type": "expect_column_value_lengths_to_equal",
      "meta": {}
    },
    {
      "kwargs": {
        "column": "id_person",
        "regex": "^WPS*|^APS*"
      },
      "expectation_type": "expect_column_values_to_match_regex",
      "meta": {}
    },
    {
      "kwargs": {
        "column": "some_other_id",
        "value": 19
      },
      "expectation_type": "expect_column_value_lengths_to_equal",
      "meta": {}
    }
  ]
}
```

I would like to find a way to filter out all the relevant list elements that contain the the values `['id_person', 'some_other_id']` under the nested key 'column' and return the dictionary format. The code below works.

```
def filter_nested_dict_list(nested_config, value_to_find):
  filtered_nested_config = {'expectations':[]}
  for position, element in enumerate(nested_config['expectations']):
    if value_to_find in element['kwargs']['column']:
      filtered_nested_config['expectations'].append(nested_config['expectations'][position])
  return filtered_nested_config

col_expectations = ['id_person', 'some_other_id']
filtered_dict = []

for col in col_expectations:
  filtered_dict.append(filter_nested_dict_list(id_config, col))
```

with the result being

```
{
  'expectations' : [
    {
      "kwargs": {
        "column": "id_person",
        "regex": "^WPS*|^APS*"
      },
      "expectation_type": "expect_column_values_to_match_regex",
      "meta": {}
    },
    {
      "kwargs": {
        "column": "some_other_id",
        "value": 19
      },
      "expectation_type": "expect_column_value_lengths_to_equal",
      "meta": {}
    }
  ]
}
```

In this  example is works well with two values_to_find, however as the list grows I'd rather not have so many for loops. So my question is- is there a neater way than running those for loops and hardcoding the nested dictionary structure?

Any improvement suggestions would be very much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The `pandas` module can do this.
You can make a `pandas.DataFrame` from the 'expectations' list and filter out the values you don't want quite easily.

[This](https://towardsdatascience.com/8-ways-to-filter-pandas-dataframes-d34ba585c1b8) provides some examples on how to do it.